# Constructing a missing-dummy; why doesn't SPSS recognize the 'missings'?

Tags: logistic, spss

A short question concerning the constructing of a 'missing-dummy', which I will consequently add to my logistic regression. This missing-dummy gives value '1' to the cases where data concerning a specific variable is missing and value '0' to the cases which have data.

I've used this command in SPSS, but in some way the missing values are not recognized.
( recode v204 (-2 -1=1)(else=0) into authomis ).

A cross-tabulation of v204 and authomis shows that the missing-dummy only has a '0'-category, regardless the fact that there are over 400 cases (on a total of 40.000) which have a missing on variable v204. Has this to do with how the missings are marked in variable v204? 
I can't think of any other reason. Hopefully you can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't use SPSS, so how does SPSS represent missing? Your code appears to mean: if the value is -2 or -1, code the new variable as 1; otherwise code it as 0. All new values being 0 implies that no values of the original were -2 or -1. That is something you can check.

Comment: This is an invalid way to deal with missing data, changing the meaning of the categorical variable and producing uninterpretable estimates.  Multiple imputation is much preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Your results don't have to do with the way missing values are marked.  On the face of it, you need to put a comma between "-2" and "-1".  Then you'll be recoding those values into a "1".

But that contradicts your first paragraph, which says it's the cases that are missing values (not those with "-2" or "-1") that should be assigned a "1".  (Where did the "-2" and "-1" come from?)

If you really want to assign a "1" when v204 has a missing value and a "0" otherwise, then use:

```
recode v204 (lo thru hi = 0) (else = 1) into NewVariable.
exe.
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you set -1 and -2 as a user-defined missing? If that's the case, you'll need to state "Missing" instead of their defined values:

```
RECODE v204 (MISSING=1) (ELSE=0) INTO authomis.
EXECUTE.
```

The `(MISSING=1)` option will take care of both user-defined and systematic missings. If you just have been using systematic missing (aka, just a "."), then you can replace that with `(SYSMIS=1)`.